# Omxplayer don't show video output of rtsp stream

Tags: pi-3, camera, omxplayer, rtsp

i'm trying to play fullHD rtsp stream from IP camera on PI3 (OS raspbian).
I tested stream url `rtsp://uss:pss@192.168.200.74` with vlc and mplayer booth show video correctly. When omxplayer opening local video file show video well too, but when opening rtsp stream only print stream info and keep running in console but show no video. (I'm not sure, but by high ethernet activity  omxplayer probably reading stream)
Use of `--display` (with values 0-5) don't help.

Big thanks for any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Ps: I'm relay sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Actually i still don't solve this problem but, [vlc with hw acceleration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=195221) can be used instead of omxplayer to play hd stream in realtime.